# mongodb full text search index all fields vs index one field

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

Currently lastest MongoDB stable version is v2.4.6, full text search is in beta state.

Which one will be faster:

1. To create one field named "text" and extract all text info from all other fields and concatenate them into field - "text" and index that field ("text")

   So that will look like

   ```
    db.collection.ensureIndex( { "text": "text" } );
   ```
2. Just index all fields:

   ```
   db.collection.ensureIndex( { "$**": "text" } );
   ```

Which one is better in performance and in disk storage requirements?

Comment: Have you done any testing? As it's still a beta as you mentioned, I'm not sure I'd do too much planning on it being one way or the other right now. It would seem inefficient to duplicate all of the text fields of your documents so so you could have a combined index.

Comment: A bit of testing will tell you why selectivity of the index is quite important, I mean imagine indexing the entire table, not much of an index then, you might as well just replace your table with the index

Comment: you can try to make two collections with the indexes you mentioned, enable profile and will make it clear. ps: make sure you have enough data into the database to be representative.